# Add forgein key after creating tables

Tags: mysql, sql

I have following problem:
the table "tblverleihdaten" is supposed to implement or reference the K_Nr column from the table "tblkunden" I've already created both tables but now I don't know how I can alter them to refrence each other like in the picture. I've been searching online but couldn't transfer any of the solutions on my problem.
[image: diagram of the database]

Comment: Images aren't useful please add table definitions as text and confirm they are all using the same engine.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

simp,y alter the table tbverleihdaten with these statements

```
ALTER TABLE tblverleihdaten
ADD FOREIGN KEY (K_Nr) REFERENCES tblkunden(K_Nr); 
ALTER TABLE tblverleihdaten
ADD FOREIGN KEY (L_Nr) REFERENCES tbllaptops(L_Nr);
```

For more [information](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/create-table-foreign-keys.html)

But then you only can add rows to tbverleihdaten  if a corresponding Id exists in both other tables

Comment: This doesn't work for me I get following error message: ALTER TABLE tblverleihdaten
    -> ADD FOREIGN KEY (K_Nr) REFERENCES tblkunden(K_Nr);
ERROR 1005 (HY000): Can't create table `awp`.`tblverleihdaten` (errno: 150 "Foreign key constraint is incorrectly formed")

Comment: then show please the complete create tables for your database.

Comment: I really only created the columns with their datatypes I didn't do anything else.

Comment: Look when i asked for you to provide information, it is because i can not understand your problem see here https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=mysql_8.0&fiddle=05a5a48bb6df4447a579198a7ac7b425  it does work as i wrote, so there must be something different that is not working

Comment: I'm sorry for the inaccurate explanation but actually your example right here solved my problem. What I was missing was the ID. Thank you very much!